# PDO connection to MySQL database refused

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I am trying to connect to my NearlyFreeSpeech MySQL database.  I can login through PHPMyAdmin but not through PDO.  I am using this code

```
 $dbconn = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname='.$config['db'].'; port=3307', $config['user'], $config['pass']);
```

Where $config is defined in a separate file.  The error I get is:

```
Warning: PDO::__construct() [pdo.--construct]: [2002] Connection refused (trying to connect via tcp://127.0.0.1:3307) 
Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

and then eventually

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in...
```

If I use

```
mysql:host=localhost
```

The error I get is

```
Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

Now I assume "Connection refused" is better than "No such file or directory", but I don't know where to go from here.  Any idea why this is happening?  Thank you for your help.

Comment: It doesn't seem right - the DSN in `new PDO` call mentions port 3307 but the error message has connection refused to port 3306 - so which is it?

Comment: sorry that's because I copied and pasted different things.  But I've tried both and changing the port makes no difference.

Comment: Any reason you are trying 3307?

Comment: Because it currently doesn't work with the default 3306 and I saw something on the internet about using 3307 instead so I thought I'd give it a try.

Comment: Are you sure MySQL is running on the same server as PHP? If not, you should specify something other than "localhost" or "127.0.0.1".

Comment: @george: what port does mysql listen? Is mysql even started and operates well?

Answer (score 1):

Try my existing functions and constant variables, you may also change those constant to an array variable you have.

```
define("SERVER_SQL_VERSION","mysql");
define("SQL_SERVER","localhost");
define("SQL_PORT","3306");
define("SQL_USERNAME","root");
define("SQL_PASSWORD","");
define("SQL_DB_NAME","db");

if(!function_exists('pdoConnect')) {
    function pdoConnect() {
        $pdo = new PDO(SERVER_SQL_VERSION.":host=".SQL_SERVER.";dbname=".SQL_DB_NAME."", "".SQL_USERNAME."", "".SQL_PASSWORD.""); 
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        return $pdo;
    }
}
```

There might be an issue about your concatenation, this must be working...

I also seperated the SERVER_SQL_VERSION, and added a functions to check if the driver is available...I am using the XAMPP software and only mysql and sqlite is active, if you/others try to use postgresql and so on...that must be working as well.

```
if(!function_exists('check_sql_version')) {
    function check_sql_version() {
        $sql_available = false;     //make it false yet
        foreach(PDO::getAvailableDrivers() as $key => $val) {
            if(SERVER_SQL_VERSION == $val)
            {
                $sql_available = true;
            }
        }
        //check now if sql_available is true or false
        if($sql_available == true)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

So a sample should be considered:

```
if(!check_sql_version()) {
    echo '('.SERVER_SQL_VERSION.') is not available, you only have this drivers:<br/>';
    foreach(PDO::getAvailableDrivers() as $key => $val) {
        $key = $key + 1;
        echo $key.') '.$val.'<br/>';
    }
    exit(); //exit and dont proceed
}
$stmt = pdoConnect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM accounts");
$stmt->execute();
```

I hope it helps!