# php oop pdo connection refused?

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to use connect to database, however I get this error, I am running this on php terminal.

I checked out other sources as well like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267727/pdo-connection-to-mysql-database-refused?rq=1) but didn't have the answer I was looking for

Any suggestions or best practices ?

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refusedsomething went wrong
```

Db.php

```
<?php 

error_reporting(-1);

class Db{

    private $db_host;
    private $db_user;
    private $db_name;
    private $db_pass;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db_host = "127.0.0.1";
        $this->db_user = "root";
        $this->db_pass = "";
        $this->db_name = "eli9";

        try{
            $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=eli9", $this->db_user, $this->db_pass);
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            echo "connected sucessfully \n";

        }

        catch(PDOexception $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();

            echo "something went wrong \n";
        }

    }


}
```

index.php

```
<?php

require_once 'Db.php';

$db = new Db();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, works for me

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->db_host;dbname=$this->db_name", $this->db_user, $this->db_pass);
```

you set variable into `$this->db_host = "127.0.0.1"` but didn't use into connection

try this without class till you get connected and use `$db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);` to check if there any error

also try port `8889`

```
try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306,dbname=eli9", 'root', '');
    $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
    echo "connected";
    } 
catch (PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: thanks but still didnt work, i recently updated to php 7 i was using 5.1 before

Comment: i think i figured it out

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @addie code, i was able to find the problem, and it was the following

1) i originally was not using a port number

2) i changed the port number to 8889 instead of 3306

so here is the final code for Db.php

```
<?php 

error_reporting(-1);

class Db{

    private $db_host;
    private $db_user;
    private $db_name;
    private $db_pass;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db_host = "127.0.0.1";
        $this->db_user = "root";
        $this->db_pass = "root";
        $this->db_name = "eli9";

        try {
            $db = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=8889,dbname=eli9", 'root', 'root');
            $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
            echo "connected";


        } 
        catch (PDOException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }


    }


}
```

Thank you @addie, but my pervading question is why do i need to include the `port` in the pdo if that is not the php manual ?

Comment: are you using MAMP?